# Phonegap : Back button not working

Tags: android, cordova, back-button, navigateurl

I have disabled the back button in `menu.html` page. Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18184497/backbutton-confirm-exit-app-anroid-phonegap-jquery)
 i have successfully quit my app on pressing back button on phone.

But this causes back button not working on any other page.

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false); //Listen to the User clicking on the back button
}
```

I want to navigate to `Menu.html` page when cliked on back button on phone. I have tried this but failed.

```
function onBackKeyDown(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    navigator.notification.confirm("Are you sure you want to go to Menu page?", onConfirm, "Confirmation", "Yes,No"); 
    // Prompt the user with the choice
}

function onConfirm(button) {
    if(button==2){//If User selected No, then we just do nothing
        return;
    }else{
        window.loacation="menu.html";// Otherwise navigate to Menu Page
    }
}
```

how can i link to menu page when cliked on back button?

Comment: There's a huge typo in your code: `window.loacation="menu.html";`  should be  `window.location="menu.html";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use `window.location.replace("menu.html")`