# Back button in Android App not working to exit the application

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

I am using **Cordova version 3.6** to create my first mobile application. I want to use the back button of the device to exit the application when reached the home page. I went through the following resources  however am not able to achieve the purpose.

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.6.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#backbutton

[PhoneGap - android exit on backbutton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338337/phonegap-android-exit-on-backbutton)

[backbutton confirm exit app android + phonegap + jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18184497/backbutton-confirm-exit-app-android-phonegap-jquery)

My Code:

Js:

```
function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }

function onDeviceReady() {
// Register the event listener
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
}

function onBackKeyDown() {
document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e){
if($('body').is('#main')){ //main is the home page id.. 
    e.preventDefault();
    navigator.app.exitApp();    
} else {
    navigator.app.backHistory()
}
}, false);
}
```

HTML:

Thanks for your time and efforts.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a listener to the backbutton again in the event handler doesn't make much sense. So remove `document.addEventListener` from `onBackKeyDown()`. And pass the event to the function.

```
function onBackKeyDown(e) {
  if($('body').is('#main')){ //main is the home page id.. 
    e.preventDefault();
    navigator.app.exitApp();    
  } else {
    navigator.app.backHistory()
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly does not work? Is onBackKeyDown triggered when you press the key?

Comment: When I press the key it takes be back to the previous page and does not quit the application.

Comment: OK, but is onBackKeyDown triggered when you press the key? Put an alert or console.log in it to check.

Comment: No the alert is not showing up too. as per the following answer it could be because of the cordova.js. However since there are platform based cordova.js files; I am not too sure how to include it into the code.

Answer (score 0):

You must add
<script type="text/javascript" src="yourpath/cordova.js"> </script>

to you html file. Type true place for your path

Comment: Yeah the cordova.js is not included; however I can't find it in the project directory. Are index.js & cordova.js the same?

Comment: No cordova.js is other file provided by Cordova SDK. It is inside www dir

Comment: It's missing in the www folder however I read somewhere that it's located in the platforms\android\platform_www for android and respective plaform directory. I could see it there. But now I am confused if I need to paste it in the main www directory and include in the index.html or give the entire path? In the former case if I build an iphone app won't there be a conflict between the 2 cordova.js files? Thanks for your time.